# Validating Django admin parent form and inlines data simultaneously

Tags: django, django-admin

I have combined two models form `User` and `UserPhone` using `TabularInline` in **admin.py**, but when i save both models data with single submit button I can only detect changes of `User` model

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
     print "form:",form.changed_data
```

but i need to check changes of `UserPhone` model data also when i save both model data on a single submit.

```
    Admin.py

    class UserPhoneInline(admin.TabularInline):
        model = UserPhone

    class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ()

        inlines = [
                UserPhoneInline,
            ]
        def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
            obj.save()
            print "form:",form.changed_data,"change:",change

    class UserPhoneAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ()
        list_filter= []
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, if your model `Userphone` is an inline to your model `User`, you probably want to remove those lines since it is unecessary:

```
 class UserPhoneAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ()
    list_filter= []
```

Then if you want to access both forms data an approach i can see is to override the `clean` method of `BaseInlineFormSet` like so, (add this to `admin.py`):

```
class InlineFormset(forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        for form in self.forms:
            for field in form.changed_data:
                print (form.cleaned_data[field])
```

Just so you understand, I think you misunderstood what `changed_data` is. This is from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.changed_data):

> The changed_data attribute returns a list of the names of the fields
>   whose values in the form’s bound data (usually request.POST) differ
>   from what was provided in initial. It returns an empty list if no data
>   differs.

Therefore, in my solution I use it to see what data has changed when you sumbit the form. Then I use `cleaned_data` which is a dict of every value that has been validated by the form and access the value coresponding to the field that has changed. Feel free to costumize what you print.

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention you need to add this line to your inline declaration:

```
class UserPhoneInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = UserPhone
    formset = InlineFormset #line to add
```

Comment: I Just want to know the object that we are going to save with other fields also. is there any option to get full object in clean method? or can we use save_model function in "InlineFormset" class ?

Comment: How we can check weather we are adding or editing data?

Comment: You seems to have multiple different questions... What do you mean by _full object_ ? And for me adding data and editing data is the samething isn't it ?